# django ORM : query of three models

Tags: python, django, django-orm, postgresql-9.1

Hi I wondering if someone can help me with this problem as I am new to django.

I have the following models

```
class Article(models.Model):
    articleid = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=20)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)

# Each article can only have one ArticleTone
class ArticleTone(models.Model):
    label = (
    ('sad', 'Sad'),
    ('happy', 'Happy'),)
    articleid = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="article")
    tone = CharField(max_length=10,choices=label,blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('tone',)
 # Each article will have 5 keywords
class ArticleKeywords(models.Model):
    articleid = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="article")
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False, null=False)
```

I am able to get the top 20 entities using this query.

```
 ArticleKeywords.objects.values('articleid').annotate(result=Count('keywords')).order_by('-result')[:20]
```

and able to get articles that are sad or happy using something like this

```
ArticleTone.objects.filter(name= 'sad');
```

But how do I put the pieces together to get all the articles that contain the top 20 sad or happy articles. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/).

```
from django.db.models import Q
q = Q(name='sad') | Q(name='happy')
ArticleTone.objects.filter(q).values('articleid').annotate(result=Count('keywords')).order_by('-result')[:20]
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is not actually giving me the top 20 sad or happy articles (based on their occurrence in an article. Either way thanks for your help. going to poke around a bit more to get it